# Unable to locate MatSnackBar element in protractor e2e test

Tags: javascript, angular, protractor

I am not able to locate MatSnackBar element using protractor.

This is how I display snack bar.

```
const snackBarRef = this.snackBar.open('Book added.', 'Undo', {
  duration: 300000
});
```

This is e2e test.

```
const snackBar = element(by.tagName('simple-snack-bar'));
browser.wait(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(snackBar), 30000);
element(by.tagName('simple-snack-bar')).getText().then(function (val) {
  console.log(val);
  expect(val).toEqual('Book added');
});
```

Test code fails with this error.
`Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.`

Comment: Hi, did you tried to add .then(() => browser.sleep(60_000)) and manually check that the element by tag name 'simple-snack-bar' is indeed present on the page.
Also, when the application is app and running, you can manually execute getElementsByTagName() to verify the element exists. by.tagName() uses the same function internally.

Comment: I found that this issue occurs because I cannot indicate element outside of root using element function

Comment: You should be able to access any element on the page that is outside the root via browser.driver.findElement(by.id('you-element-name')).

Comment: I tried `const snackBar = await browser.driver.findElement(by.tagName('simple-snack-bar'))` but it fails as well.

Comment: Weird. I have just created a new Angular app, and added this in index.html `<body>
  <p id="outside-app-root">outside app root</p>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>`, and I have edited a pre-generated test to `it('should display welcome message', async () => {
    await page.navigateTo();
    expect(await element(by.id('outside-app-root')).getText()).toEqual('demo app is running!');
  });` and it fails with the `Expected 'outside app root' to equal 'demo app is running!'.`., which is ok!

Comment: To save us both some time, can you push the failing example somewhere so we can take a look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your message, @dplavcic.
The reason that my code didn't work is that snackbar was out of angular root. So I have to use `browser.driver.findElement()` instead of `element()`, and finally have solved the issue.

Something like:

````
public getSnackBar(): promise.Promise<string> {
    const snackbar = browser.driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.tagName('simple-snack-bar')), 10000);

    return snackbar.getText();
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

The time out is from the browser.wait of 30 second, so the application cannot find the elemnt with in that time . so increase the time out as :

**add below property to your config file:**

```
jasmineNodeOpts: {defaultTimeoutInterval: 40000}
```

**About element not found**

1. make sure elemnt is not inside iframe or shadown , if so , then switch to parent before accessing it
2. use promise chaining properly or use await instead

> ```
>   it('should find an element by text input model', async function() {
>     await browser.get('app/index.html#/form');
>
>     var username =element(by.model('username'));
>     await username.clear();
>     await username.sendKeys('Jane Doe');
>
>     var name = element(by.binding('username'));
>
>     expect(await name.getText()).toEqual('Jane Doe');
>
>   });
> ```